# How to prevent page break happened while printing?

Tags: html, css, printing

I am printing my html, but during print preview section it doesn't show any page break, but when print it out, it will show page break every div i printed. This is my css for div.

```
.label{
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 1.97in;
    height: 1.57in;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px dotted;

    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `page-break-after: always;` from your CSS. Perhaps just change `always`.

Comment: Sorry, with or without the page break also caused the same thing.

Comment: @Crazy Are you you don't have any other CSS? Do the divs take up more than half the paper vertically?